# High dimensional spherical Gaussian

Tags: geometry, gaussian

I would like to know how to find the expected squared distance to the origin of a $d$-dimensional spherical Gaussian centered at the origin with variance $\sigma^2$. Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you heard of the [chi square distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386238/prove-that-frac-sum-i-1n-x-i-barx2-sigma2-sim-chi-n-1/4004006#4004006) ?

Comment: Oh I haven't heard about it. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using spherical coordinates it is a one dimensional problem, where the density function is $f(r)=Kr^{d-1}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ for $r\ge0$  The expected square distance is then $\frac{\int\limits_0^\infty r^2f(r)dr}{\int\limits_0^\infty f(r)dr}=d\sigma^2$.

Comment: Hi Steinberg, thanks for your answer. I have some questions about this. Where can I find the density function as you stated above. Once I have density function, I take derivative w.r.t $r$ and set to zero, I got $r^2 = \sigma^2(d-1)$ and I think this is the expected squared distance to the origin. Am I right?

Comment: The integral table appears to be in error.  I have corrected the answer using integration by parts.

Comment: To get the density function use  $r^2=\sum x_k^2$ and convert to spherical coordinates.  Spherical symmetry means all the angles can be integrated out..  d-1 in your answer can't be right.  d=1 leads to $0$

Comment: I read in a book and it had for case $\sigma=1$, $r^2=d-1$ and it said that for general case, the result can be scaled up by $\sigma$. Are you sure your integration is correct?

Comment: Simpler direct derivation: $r^2=\sum x_k^2$  Gaussian density $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$  Your question: is $\int_{R^d} r^2 \prod g(x_n)dA$ which is the sum   of $d$ terms each of which is $\int_{R^d}x^2_k\prod g(x_n)dA=\int_Rx^2_kg(x_k)dx_k=\sigma^2$.  (Note that the integral $=1$ over all $x_n$ for $n\ne k$.)  Since there are $d$ terms for $r^2$, the final result is $d\sigma^2$.  (Note my comment for $d=1$ your expression leads to $0$, obviously wrong).

Comment: Thank you, i will consider your solution.

Comment: Your question is for $r^2$, not $r$. If $r=0$ you have a point mass at the origin, not a Gaussian distributed.

Comment: So if I take the derivative of your density function w.r.t $r$ and set to zero, then I can find the value $r^2=\sigma^2(d-1)$ which makes the density function maximum. What this $r^2$ means?

Comment: I have no idea where you got that approach.  In general you are looking for $\int_Rx^2f(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ is the density function, which is the derivative of the distribution function.  Are you mixing up these two functions?

Comment: Oh maybe I misunderstood something here. I will have a look carefully. Anyway, thanks for your answer